# My Code is too slow( uses jdbc, oracle.sql.BLOB and searches a string in the blob)

Tags: java, jdbc, blob

Below is my code snippet

```
    PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    System.out.println("preparing sql ststement: " + query);

    ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
    System.out.println(" result stored in result set ");
    while(result.next()){
        try{
            int readCount = 0;
            oracle.sql.BLOB blob=((OracleResultSet)result).getBLOB("payload");
            InputStream in=blob.getBinaryStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(in));  
            String total="";   
            String str;   
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {   
               total += str;   
               //System.out.println(total);
            }   
            System.out.println(total);
            in.close();
```

the line `ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();` takes approximately 1 minutes to execute.
but, the conversion of Blob data to text string takes 4 minutes
below is that part of the code

```
oracle.sql.BLOB blob=((OracleResultSet)result).getBLOB("payload");
                InputStream in=blob.getBinaryStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(in));  
                String total="";   
                String str;   
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {   
                   total += str;   
                   //System.out.println(total);
                }
```

and then, a search for a string is done in 'total' based on that the result set columns are
stored in hashmap.

can someone suggest how to make this processing faster ?

Comment: What is the size of your Blob?

Comment: blob size is less than 200kb.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the search step into the SQL fragment that you pass to executeQuery, so that the database does the search instead of the Java code?

Otherwise, the Blob interface supports more direct methods to get the data than using a stream, e.g. getBytes() can get a byte array that can be passed to a String constructor, or e.g. position(), which searches the blob for a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I see several possible enhancements, given the information you provided. Not all might apply though:

1. Store structured data instead of blobs. An RDBMS is best used when searchable information is stored in normalized tables and columns. Searching inside of blobs is not what an RDBMS is made for.
2. Use the full-text search capabilities of Oracle
3. Use a real search engine, such as Lucene
4. Use a StringBuilder instead of concatenating strings and thus generating tons of garbage.
5. Search in the lines you just read, ans stop reading as soon as you found what you were looking for, instead of searching only once you have read the whole BLOB in memory

Answer (score 0):

For the first part (the slow sql query) I can't provide much help since we do not know the query, the size of your blob and your database configuration. However if the blob is not too large, this is not a natural response time. You should really use either Oracle Text features or a third party search engine as Lucene. This usually makes a huge difference in search response times.

For your second problem (reading the blob), I believe that you are going to see some improvement from the following:

- Use a buffer size other than the default (8K) for the `BufferedReader` i.e. 64 or 128K. You can try which value provides better results in your case.
- Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings

As an additional thing to watch out for, use the constructor of the `InputStreamReader` that takes a character set argument and set it to the same character set your database is configured for. The code you are currently using, has the potential to corrupt your data if they are UTF8

Comment: blob size is less than 200kb.The conversion (blob to text) , searching and storing the result in map is taking time. i will make changes as suggested.

Comment: @DeepakPandey It seems to me then that either your database has a big load or its connection is very slow. If you get the sql query and execute it manually from an Oracle client, is it still slow?

Comment: the sql query is not slow..i had executed the sql query manually on sql developer and it was executed in just above a minute.
firstly, I will implement the things suggested here.